# how to overcome this sequelize association problem

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I've read the documentation and researched a lot but I still couldn't find a solution to this problem, could someone give me a light?
What am I doing wrong?

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\Marlon\Desktop\Projeto\EuroKT\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:49   
      throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);
      ^

Error: User.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
    at Function.belongsToMany (C:\Users\Marlon\Desktop\Projeto\EuroKT\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:49:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marlon\Desktop\Projeto\EuroKT\backend\dist\src\data\models\user.js:81:6)
```

**User class:**

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { DbInstance } from '../../main/context';
import { Attributes } from '../../commons/Helpers';
import * as Config from '../../config.json';
import Permission from './permission';
import Project from './project';

var _reSync = Config.Database.ForceSync;
var _instance = new DbInstance().getInstance();

class User extends Model {

  id!: number;
  status: string;
  name!: string;
  registryCode!: string;
  phone!: string;
  email!: string;
  password!: string;
  permissionId!: number;

}

User.init({
  id: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  status: {
    type: new DataTypes.CHAR(2)
  },
  name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(30),
    allowNull: false
  },
  registryCode: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(12),
    allowNull: false
  },
  phone: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(12)
  },
  email: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(50)
  },
  password: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(100)
  },
  permissionId: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'Permission',
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
}, {
  sequelize: _instance,
  tableName: 'User',
  timestamps: false
});

User.belongsTo(Permission, { foreignKey: 'permissionId', as: 'Permission' });
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: 'User_project' });
User.sync({ force: _reSync });
export default User;
```

**Project class:**

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { DbInstance } from '../../main/context';
import * as Config from '../../config.json';
import User from './user';

var _reSync = Config.Database.ForceSync;
var _instance = new DbInstance().getInstance();

class Project extends Model {

  id!: number;
  status: string;
  name!: string;

}

Project.init({
  id: {
    type: new DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  status: {
    type: new DataTypes.CHAR(2)
  },
  name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(30),
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize: _instance,
  tableName: 'Project',
  timestamps: false
});

Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'User_project' });
Project.sync({ force: _reSync });
export default Project;
```

I want the sequelize to create the N:N 'User_Project' relationship table automatically.
was using this documentation as an example https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define all associations of all models AFTER defining all your models. For instance in a separate js-file or define a function 'associate' in each model and call these functions later after registering all the models.

Comment: By creating a method as you suggested, to go from model to model in a synchronous mode, the problem was totally corrected and it was able to automatically generate the relationship table, thanks for the light